# Cursor delete doesn't work like expected

Tags: android

I have recycler view with implemented swipe to delete with undo buttons. So when I leave the activity I have to delete all pending removal items.
I do it with this methods:

```
public void removeAllPendingRemoval() {
    isOnScreen = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < mPendingRunnables.size(); i++) {
        long id = mPendingRunnables.keyAt(i);
        Runnable pendingRemovalRunnable = mPendingRunnables.get(id);
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(pendingRemovalRunnable);
        removeById(id);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();        
}

private void removeById(long id) {
    Uri uriWithId = Uri.withAppendedPath(mContentUriWithTable, String.valueOf(id));
    mContext.getContentResolver().delete(uriWithId, null, null);
    mPendingRunnables.remove(id);
    if (isOnScreen) {
        int position = getPositionById(id);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);            
    }
}
```

I call removeAllPendingRemoval() in onPause method of my activity. But if I quickly switch to another activity that use the same db table there are items that have to be already deleted. And if i wait for some time or reopen activity they will be deleted to. I solved this problem by calling removeAllPendingRemoval() 2 times:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    mAdapter.removeAllPendingRemoval();
    mAdapter.removeAllPendingRemoval();
    super.onPause();
}
```

But it seems like really bad practice. How can i cope with this problem?

Comment: i think ur table contents successfully deleted on your first call... the activity your moving may hold your old values.. try to refresh your that activity

Comment: my new activity makes a query from the same table, so if all worked fine with delete there would be no problem

Comment: it may resumes with old data man... Check it